# PHP foreach warning

Tags: php, html, mysql, foreach, warnings

I have a table in html that is populated by a mysql backend. I keep getting the warning "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" I am using the php foreach function but this is inside my html. I have been trying to do an `if(is_array())` within this code but it doesnt seem to be working. Thanks in advance!

```
            <?php foreach($rows4 as $row4): ?> 

            <tr style="
                margin: 0; padding: 0; border-collapse: collapse;"
            >

                <td style="
                    border: 1px solid grey;"
                >
                    <form action="" method="post"> <?php echo $row4['DispatchTicketDate']; ?> </form> 
                </td>

                <td style="
                    border: 1px solid grey;"
                >
                    <form action="" method="post"> <?php echo $row4['LoginUserName']; ?>  </form>
                </td>

                <td style="
                    border: 1px solid grey;"
                >
                    <form action="" method="post"> <?php echo $row4['DispatchTicketNote']; ?>  </form> 
                </td>
            </tr>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Can you post what $rows4 contains???

Comment: Just `var_dump( $rows4 );` before you go into the loop and see what the output is.

Comment: can you show your array structure...

Comment: Your attempt was already correct - this error means that rows4 is not iterable. var_dump it to see what value it actually contains.

Comment: I understand that $row4 has no data. If the user clicks on a different option, it is quite possible that $row4 will have data. Sometimes it might and sometimes it might not. I just do not know how to error check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the size of the array before proceeding:

```
if (sizeof($rows4) > 0) { 
  foreach($rows4 as $row4):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

your mysql backend have to always return an array, like that:

```
$rows4 = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM news WHERE cat=?i", $cat);
```

or

```
$rows4 = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

returning empty array in case if no data found

this way you will never have such a proplem